# What will this return? getElementById.children[index]

Tags: javascript

If there are 3 child nodes, and I refer to one past the final child node, what will this return?

In other words, [0] returns first node, [1] returns second node, [2] returns third node, but [3] returns what?

```
document.getElementById("content").children[3]

<div id="content">
<div id="1" class="text"><textarea id="t1" rows="10" cols="70">First</textarea></div>
<div id="2" class="text"><textarea id="t2" rows="10" cols="70">Second</textarea></div>
<div id="3" class="text"><textarea id="t3" rows="10" cols="70">Third</textarea></div>
</div>
```

I am getting the last element div id="3" when I use [2] & [3]. Only tested this in Safari.

Comment: This is pretty easy to test :)

Comment: @AndyRay You would think, however I got two different results. I just want confirmation.

Comment: I would write a simple mock up instead of posting on SO

Comment: If you use developer tools, you'd see that out of index access attempts on DOM children will return undefined.

Comment: @ZackTanner Is that so? I don't get undefined. If you can find the documentation that would be great, because that would mean I have a bug

Comment: What do you get? What does your DOM structure look like? If you get cannot read property 'children' of null, it's because the element you're accessing doesn't exist.

Comment: @ZackTanner I get the the last element again. [2] & [3] both return the final element. [4] then returns undefined. I'll edit my question in a second and show you my DOM.

Answer (score 0):

The `element.children` returns

> A live HTMLCollection object, representing a collection of element
>   nodes. The elements in the returned collection are sorted as they
>   appear in the source code

That being said if you write this `document.getElementById("random").children[3]` and there isn't any element in the position with index 3, returns `null`.

More generally, when you access this collection by an index returns:

> The element at the specified index, or null if index is less than zero
>   or greater than or equal to the length property.

For more information about `HMTLCollection` please have a look [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection).